# With WPF, how does Snoop force a window refresh on a property change?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6, snoop

I have a very odd problem:

- In my C# code, if I set the "Topmost" property, the window does not stay on top.
- However, if I toggle this same property in Snoop, the windows stays on top.

My question is this: what is Snoop doing to force the window refresh?

[image]

### What I have tried

I have tried the following:

- `window.UpdateLayout()`;
- `window.InvalidateVisual()`;
- Adding a background task to continuously set this property.
- Setting `TopMost` to `false`, then `true`, to trigger a DependencyProperty refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Snoop was not doing anything special.

If I wait an additional 500 milliseconds, then it works:

```
Task task = Task.Run(
    async () =>
    {
        // Without this delay, the change will not work.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            () =>
            {
                floatingPaneWindow.Topmost = true;
                {
                    if (window.Top < 0)
                    {
                        window.Top = 0;
                    }
                        if (window.Left < 0)
                    {
                        window.Left = 0;
                    }
                }                                               
            });
    });
```

Of course, adding specific times into an application is very hacky, so I'm currently looking for some method to determine if the window is properly set up.

## Update

Puzzle solved, use the `Dispatcher` select an appropriate priority, see [WPF: In an attached property, how to wait until visual tree loaded properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037963/wpf-in-an-attached-property-how-to-wait-until-visual-tree-loaded-properly/36038245#36038245)